# How to preselect multiple rows on ng-options in a list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html list:

Basically what I am trying to do is to show this box with a list in it and the user can select multiple ones then I save it. The saving and retrieving works. The selectedList gets populated with the items user selected last time while the fullList is the entire list of choices. I want to be able to HIGHLIGHT those rows of selected choices when the data gets loaded as if restoring from the last state. I can't seem to get it to highlight/select... I searched online and haven't found anything that is similar to what I have... some help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your HTML? Do you have a model attached to the select field?

Comment: <html>
<div>
<select ng-model="selectedList" ng-options=" item.value for item in fullList.values"
multiple
</select>
</div>
</html>

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about the default browser multiselect using ng-model and ng-options, you probably just made a common mistake.

HTML for default multiselect:

```
<select multiple ng-model="selectedOptions" ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in optionList"></select>
```

Make sure you do not forget **option.value as**.
Without it a multiselect will not preselect your selected options.

**optionList**:

```
$scope.optionList = [
            {'value':0, label :'Option 1'}, 
            {'value':1, label :'Option 2'}, 
            {'value':2, label :'Option 3'}, 
            {'value':3, label :'Option 4'}, 
            {'value':4, label :'Option 5'}, 
            {'value':5, label :'Option 6'}, 
            {'value':6, label :'Option 7'}, 
            {'value':7, label :'Option 8'}
];
```

**selectedOptions**:

```
$scope.selectedOptions= [2,5];
```

Your selections will not be selected in a multi select box when you use an object array for your **selectedOptions** like this:

```
$scope.selectedOptions= [
            {'value':2, label :'Option 3'},
            {'value':5, label :'Option 6'}
];
```

Why?
Because the **option.value as** refers to the **option.value** value which is not, for example, **{'value':2, label :'Option 3'}** but **2**.

Should you think to replace **option.value as** to **option as** and use the second  **selectedOptions** list, because then it would be, for example,  **{'value':2, label :'Option 3'}**. It will not work.

For some reason the multiselect can't handle object arrays in the ng-model or it can't handle an object for the **option.value as** in the ng-options for an initial selection... Why, I am not sure.

**Conclusion:**

1. A multi select requires the **option.value** reference
2. Use a simple array for your selectedOptions while keeping the reference in mind

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to select multiple items out of list, you'll probably want to use a plugin.

https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select

[image: angular-multi-select]

or

https://github.com/amitava82/angular-multiselect

[image: angular-multiselect]

or

https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect

[image: angularjs-dropdown-multiselect]

---

To preselect several options, just bind the select field to a model and initialize that model with values.

Comment: is there anything I can do without using those plugins? isn't there something simple I can add to have that implementation?

Comment: @shaselai multi-select isn't built into Angular. you're welcome to write it yourself. to preselect a single value, just bind it to your model.